# VS 2019 deprecated API in a backwards compatible async package

Tags: c#, .net, deprecated, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2019

We have quite old VS extension which is loaded synchronously, it is derived from the [Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.package?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) and VS 2019 is telling us that we are using deprecated API.

The thing is that we need our extension to be backwards compatible with VS 2013-2019.

I have found [this example on github](https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/Backwards_Compatible_AsyncPackage_2013) which should allow to load a package synchronously on VS 2013 and asynchronously on VS 2015-2019, but i am not sure if this will help us with the warning about using deprecated API and i really want to get rid of this because according to [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/updates-to-synchronous-autoload-of-extensions-in-visual-studio-2019/) all synchronously loaded packages won't be loaded in VS 2019 v16.1.

So the question is, do you think that on VS 2019 will be package derived from [Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.package?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) with async support loaded without any warnings or i must migrate to [AsyncPackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.asyncpackage?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) and end up with two VS extensions, because the [AsyncPackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.asyncpackage?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) is not supported in VS 2013?

Thanks

Comment: How many users do you have that are stuck on VS2013?  Is this really a problem for your users, or is there some out-of-date directive that you MUST support old development systems (even if no-one uses them!)

Comment: Create two dll's. One with AsyncPackage for Studios from VS2017. And another dll for old Studios with Package (VS2012-VS2015).

Comment: you're safe to use IAsyncLoadablePackageInitialize. I've asked this Microsoft some time ago. For VS2019 it will be always supported.

Comment: Hi, any update for this issue? If the Sergey's answer is helpful for you, please consider marking it as answer, it will be beneficial to other community members which has the similar issue. Just a reminder:) –

Comment: Hello, sorry for the delay, i am now on vacation. I will give it a try next week. Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [these issues](https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=deprecated) on GitHub, especially [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/issues/177) and article i have posted in the comment i assume that i really must implement AsyncPackage and end up with two extensions, because AsyncPackage is not supported in VS 2013... hoping that someone will prove me wrong, but for now i am marking this as answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is **ProvideAutoLoad** attribute that VS 2019 is complaining about, not that you derive from the Package. So, if not absouletely required, just remove this attribute from the package class.

Comment: I have removed the ProvideAutoLoad attribute and VS 2019 is still complaining about using deprecated API. I have also found [this article](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/582676/deprecated-apis-in-vs2019.html) and if i am getting this right, i really must inherit from the AsyncPackage. Are you sure about your suggestion? These are all attributes i am using right now InstalledProductRegistration, ProvideMenuResource, ProvideOptionPage, Guid, SuppressMessage, ProvideToolWindow and AsyncPackageRegistration.

Comment: @LubošBalůsek I have some extensions that still derive from Package - ESharper, Runtime Flow, SyncBlockEdit. VS 2019 don't complain about them. But they don't support VS 2013 and don't use the AsyncPackageRegistration attribute.